# Как сделать 2 колонки на div-ах?

Tags: шаблоны, html

Задолбали кривые решения

например вот это позорное г... написанное говнокодером

http://htmlbook.ru/content/dve-kolonki-navigatsiya-sleva

(при использовании clear:both; шаблон ломается, в общем он изначально кривой)

Как сделать 2 колонки на дивах, причем 1 колонка должна быть по ширине 250px а вторая должна растягиваться на оставшиюся длинну (100%)?
эти 2 колонки должны быть в общем слое который должен растягиваться по высоте не зависимо от того в какой колонке больше контента.

Comment: Сcылка из ответа @СергейКашурин: http://web-mastery.info/templates/

Comment: И всё нормально с шаблоном на htmlbook.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютное позиционирования в вашем случае. По поводу плавающих по ширине блоков, сейчас век огромных экранов и вряд ли у вас получиться красивый веб-сайт(если вы используете графику)

Comment: Мдааа...Хотите сказать, если большой экран, то красивый сайт не выйдет? Разметку по процентам, слышали о такой?

Comment: Ну покажите мне красивый резиновый сайт с использованием графики.